Allow user with edit privileges to run scripts on a spreadsheet owned by me
I have eight scripts with assigned buttons that work for me when accessing a spreadsheet.  I would like to allow another user to run all of the scripts when clicking the associated button.
I understand that I can deploy a web app and execute under my name but when I try to deploy I get errors.  Tried doGet(e) within the script but did not use it correctly.
What needs to be done to allow another user to click a button to run a script on a spreadsheet owned by me?
1st Script:
function LockFriday()  {
  var protectRange = 'C8:D60';
  var description = 'AA Lock Friday Cells';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D60'));
  var p = spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).find(e => e.getRange().getA1Notation() == protectRange && e.getDescription() == description);
  if (p) return;
  var protection = spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).protect();
  var all = protection.getEditors();
  protection.setDescription(description).removeEditors(all);
}; 

Associated 2nd Script
function UnlockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtection = allProtections.find(existingProtection => existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C8:D60');
  if (!matchingProtection) return;
  matchingProtection.remove();
}


Avoid posting text content as images, as they're are hard to search, copy or paste.

What privileges does this other user have on the spreadsheet? If they're editors, they should  be able to execute it.

They are editors.  When they click on button nothing happens at all.  No activation.

Then, they should be able to execute. Ask them  to go to  Extensions>Apps script and click on the run button on the top.

You are right!  the script was locking and unlocking from a different spreadsheet.  So I had to give cell access to each of the cells that the script is trying to lock / unlock.  Once I did that he was able to execute the script.  Thanks so much for clarifying.

what is happening now is that when I lock, only I can unlock.  for example, after I run LockFriday cells, his cell protection changes to view only and mine will stay at can edit.  When he locks, his protection is can edit.  Is there a way in my script to specify who can edit after locking the cells?

nevermind!  I figured it out with the script entries -protection.setDescription(description).removeEditors(all);
protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');

Consider adding an answer in the answer box below if you think it'll help future viewers.

Your scripts use SpreadsheetApp.openById, so the editors should also have access to the spreadsheet referred to by this method.
Anyway, look at the execution logs; they might tell you what the problem is. For details, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Notes:
When using getRange with a spreadsheet, include the sheet name, i.e., assuming that the sheet name is Sheet1 instead of 'C8:D60' use 'Sheet1!C8:D60'.
Scripts might work differently for spreadsheet owners than for editors. When making scripts run by editors, avoid using methods like activate and getCurrentCell with spreadsheets opened by openById. Use these methods only with SpreadsheetApp.getActive().

Script was locking and unlocking from a different spreadsheet that I owned. So I had to give shared access to each of the cells that each script is trying to lock/unlock. Once I did that user was able to execute the scripts.
what happened initially is that when I locked the cells, only I could unlock. He received an error.  i.e. after I run LockFriday cells, his cell protection changes to view only and mine will stay at can edit. When he locks, his protection is can edit.
I added the following script entries and everything now works!  Both of us can run the lock and unlock scripts independently and it makes no difference who ran the initial lock script.   protection.setDescription(description).removeEditors(all);   protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');   protection.setDescription(description).addEditor('xxx@gmail.com');
